# Relatively new to Java programming but confused with 'Android studio'

Tags: java, android, eclipse, intellij-idea, android-studio

Recently I've been doing some android programming using Java and the Netbeans IDE (I have experience with Turbo Delphi, python and some c#), I have gotten to the stage of GUI's, for loops, switch statements, arrays and using some of the libraries (mainly from the course I am taking right now at my high school).

I have been taught that ALL java programs need a 'main' method and this is under `public static void main( String[ ] args ) {}`. However when using android studio (which uses the IntelliJ IDE), the base code looks different and has no 'main method'.

How does this work?

Comment: "Better" is an opinion. It works because Android programs work differently than console programs

Comment: The reason there's no "main method" is that the Android OS uses a different mechanism for executing programs.  You may want to look at this [Android tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html).  As for which IDE is better, opinion-based questions are off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: Whether or not Android Studio is better than Eclipse is up to opinion, but if you're just getting started I would recommend using Android Studio because it seems very likely that Google plans for that to be the official IDE down the road, so it will get better support with updates. Also, the vast majority of experienced developers seem to prefer it in my observance.

Comment: This question is no longer opinion based and is a good educational question. The hold needs to be lifted. Don't be discouraged @user3878789 SO can be difficult sometimes, this is a reasonable question just avoid asking for anything opinion based. Happy coding

Comment: +1....I dont't think this question deserves so many downvotes.  I was wondering the same question as I am new to Android and couldn't for the life of me find the `main` method; although realized there wasn't one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have been taught that ALL java programs need a 'main' method and this is under public static void main( String[ ] args ) {}.

That depends entirely upon your definition of "program".

> How does this work?

There are any number of ways that a developer can write Java code, that the developer might consider to be a "program", that does not involve the developer writing a `main` method:

- A Java servlet or other forms of a Java Web app do not involve a `main` method that the author of the Web app has to write
- I don't recall Java applets requiring a `main` method, but it's been a long while since I looked at those
- Plugins for other Java-based programs, like the very Android Studio that you are running, do not involve the plugin author writing a `main` method
- A JUnit test suite does not involve the test suite author writing a `main` method

It is the responsibility of *something* to load your code and run it. What that "something" is, and its expectations of your program, is up to the authors of the "something". Just because running a Java program via the **`java`** command happens to require a `main` method does not mean that *everything* running a Java program requires a `main` method.

In the case of Android, the "something" is the Android framework classes, in concert with other low-level plumbing in your Android app's process.

Answer (score 2):

Android apps don't have a `main` method because they are not JavaVM apps. A `main` method is the requirement of a JavaVM app, but not necessarily required for apps written in Java for other platforms.

In Android, there is a file called the manifest that describes all the possible entry points of your app. The most common entry points are Activities, Services, and BroadcastReceivers. If you read up on the Android documentation, it will explain how the OS will instantiate these classes.

Comment: There actually is a main(), but is is supplied by the system rather than being part of the apk. An apk does not contain an entire program, rather it is a library containing methods which will be called by the system-supplied main().